# Margin issue using DIV, HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

I'm using this free template for a study project: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LY7HS/)

My problem appears when I'm using IE7, because the botton margin of the DIV with id="outerwrapper" totally disappear.

Here you can find the css code for the outerwrapper:

```
div#outerwrapper {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 960px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #CEC7AA;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #333;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `margin` needs something to "bounce" on. It can't "bounce" against the body. So instead of using a `margin-bottom` to the child, rather use a `padding-bottom` to the parent:

```
body {
   padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I've done as you suggested, but nothing changed. It worked applied in the div#outerwrapper roles.